# What is wrong in canonical form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

We have $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x,y)=2x^2+y^3-6xy+1$. We need to verify if $M\left(\frac{9}{2},3\right)$ is local extrema. I don't want to use Jacobian method or Hessian matrix!
Here is all my steps:

---

- I found out that $d^2f(M)=4dx^2-12dxdy+18dy^2$, where $d^2f(M)$ is the second order differential of function $f$ at the point $M\left(\frac{9}{2},3\right)$
- I noted $\xi_\left(x\right)=4x_{_1}^2-12x_{_1}x_{_2}+18x_{_2}^2$, where $\xi_\left(x\right)$ is the square form of $4dx^2-12dxdy+18dy^2$. I want to use Gauss method to put in canonical form to see if is defined positive, negative or not defined.

Therefore $\xi_\left(x\right)=4x_{_1}^2-12x_{_1}x_{_2}+18x_{_2}^2=4(x_1-x_2)^2+12\left(x_2-\frac{x_1}{6}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x_1}{6}\right)^2$.

$$\rightarrow \xi_\left(z\right)=4z_1^2+12z_2^2-\left(\frac{z_3}{6}\right)^2$$ which is undefined $\Rightarrow$ $M\left(\frac{9}{2},3\right)$ isn't local extrema, but in my book it is local minimum.

> Where is my wrong?

Comment: Gauss spins in one's grave

Comment: Don't understand..

Comment: You are in dimension $2$; then, using Gauss method, you must obtain two squares and not three.

Comment: Okay, and where is my wrong? I verify again and I can't find out where is my mistake..

Comment: $4x_{_1}^2-12x_{_1}x_{_2}+18x_{_2}^2=(2x_1-3x_2)^2+\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks.. don't put as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gauss method is a great but simple method. It works by recurrence; at each step, we remove an unknown. There are two cases:

Case 1. $4x_1^2-12x_1x_2+24x_1x_3+$(terms without $x_1$)$=(2x_1-3x_2+6x_3)^2+$(terms without $x_1)$.

Case 2. $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+$(terms without $x_1,x_2)=1/4(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-1/4(x_1-x_2-x_3)^2+$(terms without $x_1,x_2)$.